# php - determine submit button clicked

Tags: php, html

I have a submit button like below:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

A.

```
if($_POST['submit'])
{
    ...
}
```

B.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    ...
}
```

C.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && ($_POST['submit'] == 'Submit'))
{
    ...
}
```

D.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    ...
}
```

My question is are they perform **same** when the submit button was clicked?

Answer (score 1):

- **A** will work, but it will produce a warning about an undefined index. It works because PHP automatically treats undefined variables and indexes as `null`.
- **B** is the usual way to do it.
- **C** will also work. It's also a useful way to do it if you have multiple submit buttons, e.g.

  ```
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete">
  ```

  You then need to test the value of `$_POST['submit']` to know which one was clicked on to submit the form. Another way this is often done is by giving each submit button a different name; then you can use method `B` to test for each name.
- **D** is useful if you might submit the form using Javascript instead of the default form submission from the browser UI, because `form.submit()` doesn't include any buttons in the parameters. Note also that you shouldn't use `name="submit"` if you might do this, because `form.submit` will then refer to that button rather than the built-in submission function.